# Remove element in multidimensional array with match PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, parent, unset

I have this multidimensional array:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 55829
        [date] => 2014-09-05 07:00:56
        [customer] => Engineering
        [server] => example
        [status] => Successful
        [version] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 55776
        [date] => 2014-09-05 06:58:30
        [customer] => Coating
        [server] => example
        [status] => Successful
        [version] => 1
    )
```

I want to be able to loop through the array and if the second level 'customer' value matches a value in this array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Engineering
    [1] => Painting
)
```

I then want to remove/unset the parent array completely if there is a match so that the first array would then be:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 55776
        [date] => 2014-09-05 06:58:30
        [customer] => Coating
        [server] => example
        [status] => Successful
        [version] => 1
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below should work where `$records` is the multi dimensional array and `$second_array` contains Engineering / Painting.

```
<?php
foreach( $records as $key => $record )
{
    if( in_array( $record['customer'], $second_array ) )
    {
        unset( $records[ $key ] );  
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `in_array`.

```
$array_to_filter = array(array(...));
$array_filter    = array(...);
foreach ($array_to_filter as $key => $value) {
    if (in_array($value['customer'], $array_filter)) {
        unset($array_to_filter['$key']);
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$types = array('Engineering', 'Painting');

foreach( $array as $key => $v ) {
    if( in_array($v['customer'], $types ) ) {
        unset($array[$key]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
$arrayBlackList = array('Engineering','Painting');

function shouldKeep($var)
{
    global $arrayBlackList;
    return !in_array($var['customer'],$arrayBlackList);
}

$filtered_array = array_filter($array1, "shouldKeep");
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
$i = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i <count($array1) ; $i++) {

   if ($array1[$i]['customer'] == $array2[0] || $array1[$i]['customer'] == $array2[1]) {

       unset($array[$i]);

       // restart
       $i = 0
   }
}
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.